# Woman spy breaks into a govt facility. Finds spheres filled with little people fighting

Tags: story-identification

This is a short science-fiction story in which a woman (who seems to be some sort of black-ops style spy) breaks into a remote secret government facility, possibly (very likely) in a cold snowy setting, like Northern Russia or Siberia or something.

She eventually enters some sort of silo/bunker that she rappels down into and becomes trapped as her climbing gear gets fouled. In this silo are suspended hollow spheres containing miniature people, who seem to be at war with each other. She gets caught up in their battles, which get out of control and eventually she finds her way out.

It turns out the whole thing is some kind of giant automated mechanical machine, for a purpose I cannot remember.

Comment: How short? Like anthology-story short or novella length?

Comment: hmmm , i feel like it wasnt a full-on novella but more of a long short-story..i'm sorry i cant be more precise than thaT.

Comment: It sounds a bit like Bruce Sterling's [*Taklamakan.*](http://www.amazon.com/Good-Old-Fashioned-Future-Bruce-Sterling/dp/0553576429) From the Amazon review: "'Taklamakan,' a high-concept piece about two freelance spies sent to a central Asian desert called Taklamakan, where the Asian Sphere is doing some sort of secret research into space flight."

Comment: that's the one! thank you so much Joe L., you are the MAN! great story!

Comment: @JoeL. You should post that as the anwser.

Comment: @jayo: I made it a formal "Answer"; it's helpful if you could check it off.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds a bit like Bruce Sterling's short story *Taklamakan,* which can be found in his anthology [*A Good Old-Fashioned Future.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553576429)

From the Amazon review:

> "'Taklamakan,' a high-concept piece about two freelance spies sent to
>   a central Asian desert called Taklamakan, where the Asian Sphere is
>   doing some sort of secret research into space flight."